# Convex QCQP in CVXOPT

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming, python, qcqp

So I have the following simple QCQP:

$$ \underset{\mathbf{x}}{minimize} \quad \mathbf{x}^{T} Q_{0}\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{q}_{0}^{T}\mathbf{x} + c_{0}  
$$ 
$$ subject \; to \quad \mathbf{x}^{T} Q_{i}\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{q}_{i}^{T}\mathbf{x} + c_{i} \leq 0 \quad i=1,2$$

Using the epigraph trick, I can rewrite this as:

$$ \underset{\mathbf{x}, \theta}{minimize} \quad \theta  
$$ 
$$ subject \; to \quad \mathbf{x}^{T} Q_{0}\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{q}_{0}^{T}\mathbf{x} + c_{0} \leq \theta\\
\quad \quad \quad \; \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \mathbf{x}^{T} Q_{i}\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{q}_{i}^{T}\mathbf{x} + c_{i} \leq 0 \quad i=1,2$$

Since the $Q_{i}$ are all positive semi definite, I can rewrite use the Choleksy Decomposition ie: $Q_{i} = M_{i}^{T} M_{i}$. The problem then becomes:

$$ \underset{\mathbf{x}, \theta}{minimize} \quad \theta  
$$ 
$$ subject \; to \quad \begin{bmatrix}
   I& M_{0} \mathbf{x}&\\
   \mathbf{x}^{T} M_{0}^{T}& -c_{0} -\mathbf{q}^{T}_{0}\mathbf{x} + \theta&\\
  \end{bmatrix} \geq 0 \\
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \begin{bmatrix}
   I& M_{i} \mathbf{x}&\\
   \mathbf{x}^{T} M_{i}^{T}& -c_{i} -\mathbf{q}^{T}_{i}\mathbf{x}&\\
  \end{bmatrix} \geq 0 \quad i=1,2
$$

Which is now an SDP. [CVXOPT](http://cvxopt.org/userguide/coneprog.html#semidefinite-programming) has a section on semidefinite programming, but I do not understand how I can formulate this problem in the format CVXOPT expects because of the $\mathbf{x}$ and $\theta$ being in the matrices.

How can I formulate the above program into something I can solve with CVXOPT in Python?

Comment: The easiest thing to do is not use CVXOPT directly, but only through a modeling framework like [cvxpy](http://www.cvxpy.org/en/latest/).

Comment: I know I'm 3 years late. But it seems like the epigraph trick already made the problem into a second-order cone optimization. cvxpy can easily solve that. No need to continue doing semidefinite programming. Here's another way to achieve this. https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/cqo.html#conic-quadratic-case-studies