# Implement QCQP in CVXOPT

Tags: normed-spaces, quadratic-programming, qcqp

I'm struggling to formulate a simple QCQP in the correct format to solve with CVXOPT.

I'm trying to implement max-margin Inverse Reinforcement Learning from the paper [Apprenticeship Learning via Inverse Reinforcement Learning](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~russell/classes/cs294/s11/readings/Abbeel+Ng:2004.pdf) (§3, p3), which is apparently the same as solving an SVM problem.

The optimisation problem in question is

[image: QCQP Optimisation Problem]

Where $t$ is a scalar and $\mu_E$, $\mu^{(j)}$ and $w$ are vectors of length $k$. My understanding from reading e.g. [this answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/8189) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2583213/convex-qcqp-in-cvxopt) is that the euclidean norm inequality can be replaced with $w^Tw \leq 1$, making this a Quadratically Constrained Quadratic Program. What I don't know is how to formulate this in a form that is compatible with CVXOPT. Should I be using the [Second Order Cone Programming](http://cvxopt.org/userguide/coneprog.html#second-order-cone-programming) method?

As an aside, I am able to formulate inequality (11), above, using the below code, it is only the euclidean norm part that has me stumped.

```
def add_optimal_expert_contraints(G, h):
    """Adds QP constraints to ensure the expert is optimal

    Assumes the 't' error term is first in the objective function,
    followed by the weight vector terms

    Args:
        G (numpy array): QP Vectorial inequality LHS constraint matrix
        h (numpy array): QP Vectorial inequality RHS vector

    Returns
        (numpy arrays): G and h, updated with new constraints
    """

    # Loop over our current set of less-than-expert policies
    for j in range(len(nonexpert_feature_expectations)):

        # For each policy, add one constraint that ensures the expert's
        # reward is greater than this policy's reward by at least a margin
        # of 't'
        G = np.vstack(
            (
                G,
                np.hstack(
                    (
                        1,
                        nonexpert_feature_expectations[j] \
                            - expert_feature_expectations
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        h = np.vstack((h, 0))

    return G, h
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The Euclidean norm constraint (12) is precisely a second-order cone  constraint, so it sounds like a good idea to use it. I don't know how you enter it in cvxopt though.

Comment: Why not use [CVXPY](http://cvxpy.org)?